# What does this Java return statement mean?

Tags: java, android

Am looking over some snippets of code and have come across a return statement which I've never seen before. What does it mean?

```
return checkDB != null ? true : false;
```

Here's the whole method code, for reference:

```
private boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try{
            String pathToDB = dbPath + dbName;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(pathToDB, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }catch(SQLiteException e){
            //database does't exist yet.
        }
        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }
```

Comment: *"Quick question"*  "What is the meaning of life?" is a 'quick' question to ask - but the *answer* takes longer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The same as `return checkDB != null`

`?:` is a "ternary operator" which. Example: `a ? b : c` does the same as a method with this body: `{ if(a) { return b; } else { return c; } }`

Comment: Yeah a cleverly disguised version of if (x == true) { return true}

Comment: Thanks Aaron and everyone else who replied. All is clear now!

Answer (score 4):

its a ternary statement can be read as

```
if(checkDB != null) {
   return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`return checkDB != null ? true : false;` is exactly the same as `return checkDB != null;`.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a [ternary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) - a nice one line variation on `if` `else` logic.